# Phrase for being on an island too long

Tags: phrase-requests

There is a term for it, I forget.  Not=[Island mad, Island cramped, Coconut crazy, Bonkers Island]

Say, living on Hawaii for a couple years.  Plenty of people, but you still might get XXX?

Comment: *and* vs *an* in the title.

Comment: I would also consider "stir crazy". Not as specific a match as the accepted answer but probably more widely understood.

Comment: Maybe "in need of a boat" or "why are you even on a island for that long?!?" or more seriously "claustrophobia"

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Is **island fever** the phrase you are looking for?

> Defined as the feeling that one is stuck on an island, and doesn’t have the freedom to just go somewhere and drive for a few hours to ‘get away’. Island fever usually hits first timers that moved to the islands after six months or a year. The sudden realization that – this is all there is. Sure Hawaii is beautiful… awesome views and landmarks… but, this is it. This is home, and it’s not a big home, it’s an island.

Source: [www.aimforawesome.com/hawaii/living-in-hawaii/](http://www.aimforawesome.com/hawaii/living-in-hawaii/)

Answer (score 1):

A more generic phrase would be "[cabin fever](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cabin_fever)",

> an idiomatic term, first recorded in 1918, for a claustrophobic reaction that takes place when a person or group is isolated and/or shut in a small space, with nothing to do for an extended period. Cabin fever describes the extreme irritability and restlessness a person may feel in these situations.

I think it's reasonable to use that metaphorically for any claustrophobic feelings from being confined in a relatively small space, such as on an island.